# How to load test submit button on website with locust?

Tags: python-3.x, stress-testing, locust

How can I implement testing a Submit button on a form with locust?

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task

class UserBehavior(TaskSet):

    @task(2)
    def index(self):
        #self.client.get("/")
        self.client.post("/", {"submit":"Good morning"})

    @task(4)
    def all(self):
        self.client.get("/all")

    @task(1)
    def page404(self):
        self.client.get("/does_not_exist")

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
    min_wait = 1000
    max_wait = 2000
```

The line

```
self.client.post("/", {"submit":"Good morning"})
```

does not simulate a button click. Can you please let me know what I have to change in the source code?

[locust_submit_btn_load_test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfrV7.png)

Comment: Is there a REST API being called when you press the "Submit" Button?

Comment: Here is the soure code I've developed with Flask and Bootstrap [fairytale.py](https://github.com/AlexanderTodorovic/fairytale/blob/master/fairytale.py)
And here is the locust file [locustfile.py](https://github.com/AlexanderTodorovic/fairytale/blob/master/loadtests/locustfile.py)
I'd like to test the @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) with Locust which is invoked when I click the Submit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP's question doesn't make much sense as stated.

> does not simulate a button click

Locust uses Requests as its HTTP client.  Requests is used to send/receive HTTP requests directly.  There is no UI or browser used at all... therefore, there is no concept of a button or any other UI element to "click".